# UIScrollView with AutoLayout and an internal UIView that should be centered vertically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have the following layout that I'd like to create in Interface Builder using AutoLayout.

- a logo at the top (fixed width, height and position
- three buttons at the bottom that should be anchored to the bottom of the controller
- a set of buttons and fields that should be centered vertically in the space between the logo and the buttons at the bottom

It's fairly easy as long as I do not introduce an UIScrollView.  I set it up this way:

- the logo is on its own anchored to the top, centered horizontally and with fixed width and height
- the buttons at the bottom are inside a container view with fixed height and that has the same width as the main view of the controller
- the buttons and fields in the middle are inside a container that is centered horizontally and that is anchored to the top and bottom to the title and bottom container, and it's got flexible height (>= a certain amount)

This works fine. But then I need to move the content when the keyboard is being displayed as the text fields would end up being below the keyboard on 3.5" devices. So I embedded everything inside an UIScrollView.

As soon as I change the edge insets of the bottom of the UIScrollView (or change the constant value of the constraint at the bottom of the UIScrollView as I tried that as well) the UIScrollView becomes a sort of infinite scrolling view.

I know that the problem is that:

- the bottom container is attached to the bottom of the controller view
- the container with the fields and buttons has variable height

If remove the constraint to the bottom from my bottom container and set the centered container to a fixed height, the UIScrollView behaves correctly, but then I cannot keep the buttons at the bottom aligned to the bottom of the screen while the keyboard isn't visibile. And I cannot keep the fields and buttons centered in the space between the title and the bottom container.

Is there any other approach?

**UPDATE**
Here's a screenshot of what my final rendered layout looks like:

[image: rendered layout on the iPhone]

And here's the current layout in Interface Builder:

[image: layout in interface builder]

The view that I called "Central View" is the one that should be centering vertically in the UIScrollView.

Right now this is done with the following constraints:

[image: Central View constraints]

But since the container view called "Bottom Buttons" is anchored to the bottom of the view called "Big Fake View" which is just a view that has the same width and height of the main view of the controller, when the UIScrollView is being resized, that container view keeps being attached to the bottom, while the "Center View" grows in height. That's where I am stuck at the moment.

Comment: First solution that comes to mind is having all the stuff not directly in the scrollView but in the container view whose height is set to equal the height of scroll view.

Comment: what effect do you want when keyboard is opened? just cut the screen size, so bottom buttons will aligned the keyboard, top aligned with screen top, and center space get shrunk and can scroll. or everything in the scrollView and can scroll. just top aligned scrollView top, bottom aligned scrollView bottom.

Comment: @SolaWing when the keyboard is open it's fine to have the UIScrollView to align its bottom to the top of the keyboard and have everything inside the UIScrollView scrollable.

Comment: so this mean when scroll up and down, you top and bottom may be hide. and center area may not at the center? You top and bottom area should have fixed height, and the center area height can be determined by controller view height. so the scrollView will have a fixed content height and work fine. and when keyboard is close, the layout should just fine.

Comment: @SolaWing actually not. The center area should always be centered vertically between the top view (title) and bottom container (buttons).

Comment: So top is alway top and visible, bottom is same instead it can at the top of keyboard? center is alway the left space center? just like change to a smaller view container?

Comment: @SolaWing I've edited the original post to further explain where I'm at and what I want to achieve. Right now even just being able to stop that UIScrollView behave like an infinite scroll would be awesome, as long as the content is rendered correctly when the keyboard isn't open

Comment: Since your top and bottom view are fixed and don't scroll by scrollView, they shouldn't be included in scrollView. or they shouldn't bind with scrollView's content height. instead you can have a scrollView, as the center view container, it's height and content height is both equal to the left height. so when keyboard show, user can scroll the center view. you also need a empty view represent the keyboard view, which have constraint with scrollView, so when keyboard popup, the scrollView frame bottom just >= keyboard frame top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73923/discussion-between-valerio-santinelli-and-solawing).